# How to remove the vertical space between the last line of code and the frame if the code is wrapped in `minted` within `algorithm`?

Tags: minted, algorithm2e

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{python}{
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{pythoncode}
x = 12
y = 3

print(x / y)
    \end{pythoncode}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{minted}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{minipage}}
\newminted{python}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{pythoncode}
x = 12
y = 3

print(x / y)
\end{pythoncode}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Old

### Reason

You can see the definition is `\kern2pt\hrule\relax` in `float.sty`:

```
\newcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
```

### Solution

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\fs@ruled}{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}{\kern-.5\baselineskip\hrule\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{python}{
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{pythoncode}
x = 12
y = 3

print(x / y)
    \end{pythoncode}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. But if I enable the `breaklines` option in `newminted`, there will be a little space added above and below the code. Is that normal?

Comment: @Jadim I have updated my answer, please see if it meets your requirements now.